# Strange oscillations with TL431 voltage reference

Tags: voltage-reference, oscillation, tl431

I have a problem with [TL431](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/TL431_FAM.pdf) voltage reference circuit:

[image]

There is no load connected to VREF25.
When I remove C8, voltage VREF25 is perfectly stable 2.5V.
But when I put C8 back into the circuit, voltage VREF25 is oscillating and I can't figure out why:
[image]

It is irony because C8 was meant to stabilize VREF25.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use capacitor with higher capacitance (470nF). It did not help.
I tried to use resistor (R10) with lower resistance (330Ω) to increase current (from 1mA to 2mA). It did not help.

**UPDATE2:**
3.3V line is this: 
[image]
I use genuine TL431 from NXP.
There's no 139kHz signal in my circuit. Actually I disconnected this voltage reference from the rest of circuitry.
I use SMD components, capacitors and resistors are 0805.

Comment: Mighty strange. Is anything else in the circuit operating at 139 kHz? Is the 3.3 V stable?

Comment: @winny 3.3V is stable, actually that is the first thing I checked. Actually it's a li-ion battery and MCP1700 LDO. No, there is nothing with 139kHz. Actually I detached all other circuitry from this voltage reference. So it was connected only to 3.3V power, and that is clean.

Comment: Please add stable 3.3 V reading and no 139 kHz anywhere else into your question. Are you using some strange super high ESL capacitor? Off-brand TL431?

Comment: @winny I updated my question. I am using cheap 0805 MLCC capacitors. I doubt there is too high ESL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the datasheet provided, 0.1uF is right at the boundary condition for oscillation (ref. figure 23). Use either a larger or a much smaller capacitance.

Comment: I tried to use bigger capacitor, it did not help. I have updated question.

Comment: @Chupacabras According to TI's datasheet, 470nF is within region of instability. Try placing a 2.2-uF cap.  By the way the datasheet says that the TLV431 is designed to be stable without caps.

Comment: Yes, I see it in the datasheet, but apparently it doesn't work for me. 470nF is in stable region, but in reality it is unstable for me :( I tried 10uF cap now and oscillations are gone. I'm going to remove that cap. It really seems it is stable without that cap. Thank you.

Comment: Capacitors are usually inserted to cut noise, not for stability. To help deciding right values they give instability regions.

Comment: The cap increases HF PSRR and gives better transient response if varying current is pulled from the TL431. 10µF is OK, you can use a much larger electrolytic like 470µF with ESR below 0R1 if you want best PSRR and lowesr noise.

Comment: What is stable region for MCP1700?